# Cached chapters of Pollard's Asymptopia?

Tags: references

These used to be available on his website online but no longer are -- can anyone provide or point to cached copies?

Comment: I found the files here: http://web.archive.org/web/20160524113206/http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Books/Asymptopia/